# Zend2 Navigation - Render Level 1 Branch Head + Children if active

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I created a menu in zend2 which works so far. Perfectly.

```
- Parent 1
-- Child Page 1
-- Child Page 2
-- Child Page 3
- Parent 2
-- Child Page 1
-- Child Page 2
-- Child Page 3
- Parent 3
-- Child Page 1
-- Child Page 2
-- Child Page 3
```

Now I'd like to only render child pages when the parent is active.
Let's say Parent 2 would be active the rendered menu would look like this:

```
- Parent 1
- Parent 2
-- Child Page 1
-- Child Page 2
-- Child Page 3
- Parent 3
```

That's my global.php config file

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Parent 1',
                'controller' => 'controllerone',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page1',
                        'controller' => 'controllerone',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page2',
                        'controller' => 'controllerone',
                        'action' => 'page-two',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page3',
                        'controller' => 'controllerone',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    )
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Parent 2',
                'controller' => 'controllertwo',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page1',
                        'controller' => 'controllertwo',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page2',
                        'controller' => 'controllertwo',
                        'action' => 'page-two',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page3',
                        'controller' => 'controllertwo',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    )
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Parent 3',
                'controller' => 'controllerthree',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page1',
                        'controller' => 'controllerthree',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page2',
                        'controller' => 'controllerthree',
                        'action' => 'page-two',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Page3',
                        'controller' => 'controllerthree',
                        'action' => 'page-one',
                    )
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

That's how i render the navigation within my layout

```
<?php
echo $this
    ->navigation('navigation')
    ->menu();
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to do that using a custom view template and calling `renderPartial()` method, or even better extending `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu`.

You'll basically have to call parent `renderMenu()` with option `$maxDepth = 0` only for non active branches.

The are plenty of methods you can use to i.e. `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper::findActive()`.

Comment: Thanks stefano but as i mentioned i'm a bloody rookie. Could you give me a little example. A couple of lines of code suffice just to get a better understand on where to place the code and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

As posted in #zftalk on irc....
You're missing setting the menu helper to only render the active branch, the docs are here: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html

```
<?php
echo $this
    ->navigation('navigation')
    ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
    ->menu();
?>
```

Should resolve your problem

Comment: I don't think that solves my problem as i need to render branch heads even if they're inactive. if a branch head is active it's children should be rendered too.